# Programatic navigation on NavigationSplitView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I have an app originally designed for iPad using NavigationSplitView. On a phone, I want it to automatically navigate to the detail view under certain circumstances. I have found the isActive property of NavigationLink, but this only works with NavigationStack, not split view. Is there a way to do this without converting everything to NavigationStack, or having to build separate views for phone and pad?

```
struct ScoringSplitView: View {
    @State var game: Game?
    @State var newGameViewModel: NewGameViewModel?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            leftPanel
        } detail: {
            if let game = game {
                GameAlertContainerView(game: game)
            } else {
                GameScoringView(game: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    var leftPanel: some View {
        if let game = game {
            return AnyView(PlayerList(game: game))
        } else if let viewModel = newGameViewModel {
            return AnyView(NewGameView(viewModel: viewModel))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Text("placeholder")
        }
    }
```

```
struct PlayerList: View {
    @ObservedObject var game: Game

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TeamNamesView(game: game)
            BattingPlayerList(game: game)
        }
        .toolbar {
            if UIDevice.isIPhone { // from an extension
                ToolbarItem {
                    NavigationLink("Score") { // isActive doesn't work
                        GameAlertContainerView(game: game)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Right now the Score button takes the user to the scoring view, but I want it to go there automatically with a back button to the player list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with the navigationDestination view modifier and isPresented:

```
@State var showScore = true
// ...
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showScore) {
            GameAlertContainerView(game: game)
        }
```

Comment: A bit more code would be good. Where does this go? Is that going to ToolbarItem?

Comment: ok, found out together with the description of navigationDestination. It's inside of the NavigationSplitScreen.

Comment: a bit more code would be good @WizardofKneup

Comment: @Andrespch, I tried. Reviewing my solution, I can see that my approach is quite complex. But at least it is working. Happy to hear about better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on both macOS and iOS, you need to use two different techniques. You need to manage different ways of navigation:

- The normal navigation via NavigationLinks
- The programmatic navigation, separate in macOS and iOS.

First, create a ViewModel (you could do theoretically without, but trust me on this)

```
@Observable
final class ViewModel {     
    /// used in Detail View of NavigationSplitView for macOS/iPad
    var selectedDetail: Detail? = nil
    /// used in Content View of NavigationSplitView for macOS
    var selectedContent: Content= = nil
    /// used to skip Content view on iOS
    var showDetail: Bool = false
    
    /// can be called from Toolbar
    func addDetail() {
        // create here
        let newDetail = ....
        #if os(macOS)
            select(content: selectedContent, detail: newDetail)
        #endif
        #if os(iOS)
            selectedDetail = newDetail
            showDetail = true
        #endif
    }

    // normal macOS navigation
    func select(content: Content?, detail: Detail?){
        selectedContent = content
        selectedDetail = detail
    }

    /// more stuff
}
```

and in the Content View:

```
  @State var model: ViewModel
```

then in body of the view:

```
 NavigationSplitView {
        LeftSideView(model: model)
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $model.showDetail){
                 if let detail = model.selectedDetail {
                     DetailView(detail: detail)
                 }
             }
        } content: {
             ContentView(model: model) //uses model.selectedContent
        } detail: {
            if let detail = model.selectedDetail {
                DetailView(model: model, detail: detail)
            } else {
               Text("Select a detail")
            }
        }
```

As you see, there are two ways to show DetailView, one via .navigationDestination and one within the Detail view.

Finally, you need to manage the standard navigation:

```
struct LinkToDetail: View {
    @Bindable var model: ViewModel
    @Bindable var detail: Detail
    let content: Detail

    var body: some View {
        #if os(macOS)
            Text(detail.title) 
                .onTapGesture {model.select(which: list, item: item)}
        #endif
        #if os(iOS)
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(model: model, item: item)
            } label: {
                Text(detail.title) 
            }
         #endif
     }
}
```

And if you think that this is too convoluted, then you are not alone. But at least it works.

I would be happy to hear how it is supposed to work. :-)